# How to make list active in Kivymd list

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

This is the code from the example. There is a kiwi markup here. But how to give this code functionality.
For example, so that after canceling the checkbox, the item disappears from the list.
I was able to achieve only to remove the icons.
I tried adding the on_release function there, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons


KV = '''
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox:


BoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class ListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

    icon = StringProperty("android")


class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        icons = list(md_icons.keys())
        for i in range(30):
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f"Item {i}", icon=icons[i])
            )


MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create a method to remove the widget from the scroll widget
that will take the `ListItemWithCheckbox` instance and remove it from the list just link following

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons

KV = '''
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox:
        # add this line that will call the remove widget when we change the check box state and will pass the 
        # ListItemWithCheckbox widget that will be removed from the list
        on_active:app.remove_widget(root)

BoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class ListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

    icon = StringProperty("android")


class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''


class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    # create method to remove list item
    def remove_widget(self, widget):
        print(widget.text)
        self.root.ids.scroll.remove_widget(widget)

    def on_start(self):
        icons = list(md_icons.keys())
        for i in range(30):
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f"Item {i}", icon=icons[i])
            )


App().run()
```